# API Google Calendar Not work

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API without success.
I'm following the tuto:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

But it doesn't work I have an error message:

> Error response
>
> Error code 404.
>
> Message: File not found.
>
> Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

Yet I'm following the steps. I post you the complete code because I have a slight doubt about the end of the script. Having already used the Outlook API, which is full of errors, I am suspicious.
If I copy/paste their script my IDE detects an error, I modified it, but I have doubts.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> nodal-algebra-193713 </title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> nodal-algebra-193713 </p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display:">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: ">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '***********';
      var API_KEY = '************';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listUpcomingEvents();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var events = response.result.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming events:');

          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()">
      onreadystatechange ="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()"
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: exactly which URL is it which is returning a 404? Just check you referenced it exactly right. See if you can visit it by pasting into your browser bar. And what error was detected by your IDE? What did you change? Does it work if you change it back to the original?

Comment: My IDE error is: Attribut onreadystatechange not allowed on element script at this point

Answer (score -2):

if I set the original code, nothing works. In the end the only thing I modified and the closing of the  tag at the end.

Original script:

```js
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange ="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">

    </script>
```

Comment: "In the end the only thing I modified and the closing of the tag at the end." this sentence doesn't fully make sense, it's not grammatical and it's difficult to understand what you mean. And if this is meant to be the answer, you need to explain whether when you modify it, does it work? What did you change it to?

Comment: Hi I'm sorry, my English is limited. the only change is to close the script tag. In the original script the tag <script> closes after the "this. onload ()". But in this form I have an error: : "Attribute onreadystatechange not allowed on element script at this point"

Comment: In _your_ original script it ends after the "handleclientload" bit, but not in the version at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js . Look closely at it. I think you just made a copying error.